# Point my hosts to User/username/Sites from Library/WebServer/Documents

Tags: apache, laravel-5, server

I (running on a macbook pro Yosemite 10.10.5) have a hosts file which consists of the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot “/Users/samir/Sites/theblog/”
    ServerName theblog.dev
    ServerAlias www.theblog.dev
    ErrorLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and for the folder at /Users/samir/Sites/theblog/, I want to be able to access it from going to http://theblog.dev, but right now the only way to access /theblog is if I copied and pasted it at /Library/WebServer/Documents, how do I change the location to Users/samir/Sites? And how do I make the url's work?

I am using laravel 5 by the way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are virtualhosts enabled with **NameVirtualHost *:80** ?

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean and where?

Comment: Apache needs a NameVirtualHost directive to enable virtualhost

Comment: Is that located in the httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

I am considering you are working with Laravel application.

Try with below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot “/Users/samir/Sites/theblog/public”
    <Directory /Users/samir/Sites/theblog/public/>
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerName theblog.dev
    ServerAlias www.theblog.dev
    ErrorLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```